# android, how to tell whether the app is in killed state by packagename

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-background

Having an android app which has service running to listen to the FCM notification.

By app in `killed` state I mean when swipe off the app from the recent activist app list, or close the app by tapping on the `home` button, or backpress on the app until the app closes (after all activities are popped out from backstack), or for any reason the OS killed the app.

There are functions could be used with the app's packagename to get some app's state info.

this one can help to tell the app is in background, but may not be killed.

```
public class ArchLifecycleApp extends Application implements LifecycleObserver {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onStop() {
        //App in background
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onStart() {
        // App in foreground
    }
}
```

this one can tell app is in FG only:

```
   boolean isAppInFG(Context appContext, String packageName) {
        boolean appInFG = false;

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses != null) {
            
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
                if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND &&
                        appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                    appInFG = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return appInFG;
    }
```

after pressed `home` button, or swipe out the app from the recent application list, the `appProcess.importance` is always 300 and is same as if the app is in background (covered by other app).

Question: in this case is there way to tell the app is killed (not just simply in background)?

Comment: If the app has been killed, then there is no process hosting the app. If you call ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses() and there is no process running that has your app's package name, you can be sure that your app is not running.

Comment: Thanks @David. I may not use the "app is killed" properly here. In my case of testing I have developer option's Don't keep activities turned on, and after swipe out the app from recent list or the app is covered by other app,  the app is still in ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses() (the app has FCM service running).
Actually my goal is to either to force re-launch the app (if it killed), or just bring the app to front from its last state. Right now I can only be sure the app is in foreground by IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. if your app has a `Service`, then when you swipe the app from the "recents" list, this will not necessarily kill the OS process. It may, and it may not (this depends a lot on the Android version and on the manufacturer's customizations). If the app is covered by another app, nothing happens: it just gets `onPause()` and then `onStop()`. This will not usually cause the OS process to be killed. I'm not sure what you are trying to detect or accomplish here. Can you describe the situation you are trying to detect/solve?

Comment: @david, I want to determine: should the app go through a fresh re-launch (app is killed) or just bring the app to front? It is when the `Service` receives msg and in service's handler code. 
Tried ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses() but apparently it always finds the app in the returned List<RunningAppProcessInfo>.
Tried with turn on `Developer Options/Don't keep activities`, with hope that the OS will kill the app so that I could test  (normally with it turned on and when swipe off the app, or make the app covered by other app the app would be `killed` by OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you wrote:

> I want to determine: should the app go through a fresh re-launch (app
> is killed) or just bring the app to front?

If you use a "launch `Intent`", this will handle all of this for you. If the app is already running, it will just bring the app to the foreground in whatever state it was in. If the app is not running, it will launch the app fresh.

To get a "launch `Intent`", you can use `PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()`